# php file working on localhost but not in server

Tags: php, mysql

This is my registration php page..!

when i get registered on **localhost** it works fine and redirect me to feedsomeinfo.php

but in server

it is redirecting me on  login_attempt.php

any clue why it is happening?

```
 <?php

    // Report runtime errors
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

    // Report all errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

    // Report all errors except E_NOTICE
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    session_start();
    include("config.php");
    function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }
    $user=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    $invitecount=5;
    $fname=ucfirst(clean($_POST['fname']));
    $lname=ucfirst(clean($_POST['lname']));

    $usern=clean($_POST['usern']);
    $emailadd=clean($_POST['emailadd']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
     $password= sha1($password); 


    $num='1';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(fname, lname, invitecount, usern, email, password,  profilepic, coverphoto,number)
    VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$invitecount', '$usern', '$emailadd', '$password', 'profilepic/friends.png', 'coverphotos/cover.png', '$num')");



         //Create query
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$emailadd' AND password = '$password'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['fname'];
                $id=$member['id'];
                $name=$member['fname'];
                $number=$member['number'];
                $expires = 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
              setcookie("email", $emailadd, time()+$expires);
        setcookie("password", $password, time()+$expires);
                mysql_query("insert into logged(logid,logdin) VALUES('$id', '$name') ");
                if($number=='1')
                { header("location: feedsomeinfo.php");

                }
                else
                { header("location: timewall.php");

                }

            }
            else{
                header("location: login_attempt.php");
                exit();
            }



    mysql_close($bd);
    ?>
```

edit :- values is not saving in database

**but**

wheni i try this code

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

session_start();
include("config.php");
function clean($str) {
$str = @trim($str);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$str = stripslashes($str);
}
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
$user=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$invitecount=5;
$fname=ucfirst(clean($_POST['fname']));
$lname=ucfirst(clean($_POST['lname']));
$emailadd=clean($_POST['emailadd']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
 $password= sha1($password); 

$num='1';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(fname, lname, invitecount , email, password,  profilepic, coverphoto,number)
VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$invitecount', '$emailadd', '$password', 'profilepic/friends.png', 'coverphotos/cover.png', '$num')");

// removed to redirect to next page and user have to login again :(

mysql_close($bd);
?>
```

d value is storing in database...!

Comment: Is there a difference between the versions of PHP on your localhost and the server? And did you change your config so the script uses the correct database?

Comment: `$passwordx` that's undefined as is `$a`. Plus, storing passwords in cookies is not a very good idea. Plus, `mysql_close($bd);` which API are you using to connect with?

Comment: @Fred-ii- removed setcookie("password", $passwordx, time()+$expires); 
but same problem :(

Comment: Reload my comment above; there were a few edits made to it.

Comment: Check the db info in your config.php file, is the credentials on the live server valid? Is your database created on live server? And are the tables created on the live server?

Comment: @Riya database authentication is the same? Database hostname is the same? Tables are the same? Rows are the same?

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is my registration page on my website after a successful registration it should be redirected to feedsomeinfo.php and it is working fine on localhost but server :(

Comment: It is redirecting to login attempt because the `mysql_num_rows($result)` is not returning any value or o rows, can you please try to see what error you are getting by putting the code in `try.. catch` block..

Comment: You may not be displaying errors. So add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and add `or die(mysql_error())` to all `mysql_query()` and did you in fact create a password using `sha1`? You're using this in `$password= sha1($password);`. Are you using `mysql_` or `mysqli_` or PDO to connect with? Also add `exit;` for each header.

Comment: Another thing; if your form's method isn't explicitly included, such as  `method="post"`, forms default to GET if omitted, and in turn, will fail "silently" because of it. I've seen that happen many times.

Comment: You also posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/29253210/

Comment: yup because of some reason...people who dont know d ans just downvote d ques...you can see above for dis ques too..

Comment: You haven't responded to any of my last two comments; so I don't know what else to tell you that will be of help, other than scrap this code entirely, and look for one that is up to date using `mysqli_` or PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()`, good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i was working on your suggestions and still no joy :(

Comment: Take my advice and stop wasting your time with this and scrap it. Check out https://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp#.VJwyRc3AHA that will get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would check:

- if the database connection is working
- if the database rows are this
  same
- add `or die(mysql_error());` to yours queries and check if there
  are some errors
- install extension to your browser `firebug` and check
  consol log while you submit your register form. Look for POST data
  and your response.